# How do I find out if window animations are enabled in settings

Tags: android

I know, I can start the Settings-Activity with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

But how do I know if the animations are enabled in the first place?

I have an animation inside a custom view and only want to show it, if the animations are enabled in the settings. If they are disabled, I'd like to ask the user to enable them the first time he starts the application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html.

You can read the flags:

- TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE
- WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE

If they are 0, then animations are disabled.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Would like to add, that if user settings are set to "Some window animations are shown", then only Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE is set to 1.0, the other one to 0.0.

Comment: How do we actually use these I tried with the `getInt()` function but kept seeing an exception and so switched to the `getInt()` with a default value but then always get the default value back :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31996851/218473 on how to retrieve those properties

Answer (score 31):

> Settings.**System**.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE and Settings.**System**.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE are deprecated from **API 17**.

So I use this method to find out.

```
private boolean areSystemAnimationsEnabled() {
  float duration, transition;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    duration = Settings.Global.getFloat(
                  context.getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1);
    transition = Settings.Global.getFloat(
                  context.getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.Global.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
  } else {
    duration = Settings.System.getFloat(
                  context.getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1);
    transition = Settings.System.getFloat(
                  context.getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.System.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
  }
  return (duration != 0 && transition != 0);
}
```

Or, you can check only for ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE...

```
private float checkSystemAnimationsDuration() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    return Settings.Global.getFloat(
        context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
        0);
  } else {
    return Settings.System.getFloat(
        context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
        0);
  }
}
```

and set your valueAnimator.setDuration() accordingly.

```
ValueAnimator alphaFirstItemAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
alphaFirstItemAnimator.setObjectValues(0.8F, 0F);
alphaFirstItemAnimator.setDuration((long)(DURATION_ANIMATION_MILLIS * checkSystemAnimationsDuration()));
alphaFirstItemAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
alphaFirstItemAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

  }
});
```

I hope it helps someone.