# How to enable Window Animations Dynamically in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to enable animations in my app, I am doing this but to no effect.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
```

I have given permssion in manifest too,

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

Please advise,

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what you are trying to achieve and the context in which you are making the above calls?

Comment: I want animations on my activity window, But this can only be achieved if user has enable Animations from Settings>Display>Animation. Now I want to dynamcally enable anmations so that it works on all androids,

Comment: Been looking around but can't find anything. It would seem strange that if it was off in the system, you'd be able to turn it on from an app. I understand that if it was on, you'd be able to turn it off for your app, but not sure bout the other way, although can't find anything to confirm that. If you don't find a solution you could consider this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529435/how-do-i-find-out-if-window-animations-are-enabled-in-settings Check if animations are off and direct a user to the display settings to turn them back on. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the settings won't work until you finish and then re-create the activity. I know this is the case for changing localisation settings and may be the same for the settings you are trying to set?

Also, just for debugging purposes, you could call `Settings.System.getInt` after `putInt` to check the system is actually storing the correct settings value.

Comment: Already checked its is storing correct nad one more thing If  enable Settings>Display>Animation Manualy, then all is well