# How to enable Animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to enable animations in my app dynamically as we do manually from Settings>Display>Animation>All Animation.

I have tried appended code but to no avail,

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE, 1);
```

Please help

Imran

Comment: make xml file in res/anim/ and write the code for animation and add  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);    Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

i think., you can do it for your app., but if you are taking it for your device means you can read the flags., if it is disabled you can intent the setting panel to open to enable it by the user.

source:
[animation enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529435/how-do-i-find-out-if-window-animations-are-enabled-in-settings)

Answer (score 0):

//  declare animation

> Animation animationSlideInLeft, animationSlideOutRight;

// Now we are giveing image view animated

```
   image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
   image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
   image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);

   animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
     android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
   animationSlideOutRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
     android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
   animationSlideInLeft.setDuration(1000);
   animationSlideOutRight.setDuration(1000);
   animationSlideInLeft.setAnimationListener(animationSlideInLeftListener);
   animationSlideOutRight.setAnimationListener(animationSlideOutRightListener);

   curSlidingImage = image1;
   image1.startAnimation(animationSlideInLeft);
   image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

// Create animation listener

```
 AnimationListener animationSlideInLeftListener
 = new AnimationListener(){

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   if(curSlidingImage == image1){
    image1.startAnimation(animationSlideOutRight);
   }else if(curSlidingImage == image2){
    image2.startAnimation(animationSlideOutRight);
   }else if(curSlidingImage == image3){
    image3.startAnimation(animationSlideOutRight);
   } 
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};
```

// and paus clear the listener

```
   @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  image1.clearAnimation();
  image2.clearAnimation();
  image3.clearAnimation();
 }
```

[Reference from here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/implement-slide-in-and-slide-out.html)

2.Same this one you can do with add xml into res/anim/ folder