# respect animator duration scale in own animation

Tags: android, android-animation

how can I respect the animator duration scale setting in own animations? Can I read the setting and multiply it to my duration or what is a good way for this?

Answer (score 12):

You can try something like this:

```
    final float animatorSpeed;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        animatorSpeed = Settings.Global.getFloat(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
                0);
    } else {
        animatorSpeed = Settings.System.getFloat(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
                0);
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. Min version: 16

Comment: Don't forget try {...} catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e)

Comment: Is it possible to disable some View from using this? I've noticed that Lottie (used to play animations that are like videos) has issues with this and I actually think it should be ignored for playback...